# Capture network log traffic using python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, automation, fiddler

I want to capture all the network log traffic of my url using python, As fiddler classic do

or tell me how can i automate fiddler, hit on my url and save all the traffic network logs by python.

I want to capture all the network log traffic of my url using python